# Sending and Reading a value from a MBO operation in SUP 2.3 with Android

Tags: android, wsdl, native-code, sup, sap-smp

I am developing a native android application with 
Sap Mobile Platform 2.3

I have an MBO with an operation inside it.
I have succesfully generated the code, and it connects and syncs well.
(...well, so far it is empty so it sync nothing so far)

All I want to do is change an argument name (a product code) for the operation's 
web service, and I want to capture the reply.
I can do so right now, by changing the argument manually at the "Test Execute" 
window of the operation.

I can't seem to get a grip on any of the generated java classes, in order
to either set the argument name nor extract the reply.

Can some SAP guru share his insight with me? thanks!

This is the webservice text copied from the browser, I have no idea what kind of WS it is, or how to handle it because my predecessor just walked away. Below is the webservice's code as shown on my browser, some nodes are collapsed to save space:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsoap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:n1="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
<wsdl:documentation>
<sidl:sidl xmlns:sidl="http://www.sap.com/2007/03/sidl"/>
</wsdl:documentation>
<wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required="true"/>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BN__BINDING">...</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BN__BINDING_soap12">...</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="IF__ZPP_PRODUCCIO_STEP1">...</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OP__ZppProduccioStep1">...</wsp:Policy>
<wsdl:types>...</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="ZppProduccioStep1">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ZppProduccioStep1"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="ZPP_PRODUCCIO_STEP1">
<wsdl:documentation>...</wsdl:documentation>
<wsp:Policy>...</wsp:Policy>
<wsdl:operation name="ZppProduccioStep1">
<wsp:Policy>
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#OP__ZppProduccioStep1"/>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsdl:input message="tns:ZppProduccioStep1"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BINDING" type="tns:ZPP_PRODUCCIO_STEP1">...</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="BINDING_soap12" type="tns:ZPP_PRODUCCIO_STEP1">...</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="ZPP_PRODUCCIO_STEP1">
<wsdl:port name="BINDING" binding="tns:BINDING">
<soap:address location="http://nostru3p.local:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zpp_produccio_step1/030/zpp_produccio_step1/binding"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="BINDING_soap12" binding="tns:BINDING_soap12">
<wsoap12:address location="http://nostru3p.local:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zpp_produccio_step1/030/zpp_produccio_step1/binding"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Can you provide more details of what you want to achieve? Do you want to know if change succeeded in the SAP system? Or you want to bring back the updated fields to the device?

Comment: I need to send a parameter called iMAufnr to this webservice, and recover the reply, with SUP 2.3, for a native Android app. (Plese see the webservice code as shown on the browser, on my edited question)